# Can I use pm2 to keep a Next.js app running

Tags: npm, amazon-ec2, next.js, pm2

I have an AWS EC2 that is just for keeping my Next.js client side running (there is no backend for it right now). Currently if I go into the terminal and enter `npm run develop`, the site runs perfectly. However, I want this process to always be running in the background of the instance. Is there a way I can do that with pm2?

I have it installed globally, but it won't let me run `pm2 start npm run develop`. BTW yes I want it running in development mode right now.

Comment: `pm2 start npm --name "next" -- run develop` should work. Notice the `--` before `run dev` to pass arguments to the underlying process.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

yes, but make sure the command exists in the package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }
```

so in this case, the `pm2` command will be

```
pm2 start npm --  dev
#in your case
pm2 start npm --  develop
```

[image]

Or to have a nice name as mentioned by @brc

```
pm2 start npm --name "next-js" -- dev
```

[image]

While running on EC2, it also good practice to save process for startup

> PM2 can generate startup scripts and configure them in order to keep your process list intact across expected or unexpected machine restarts.

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

```
pm2 startup
pm2 save
```

Answer (score 16):

Adding to best answer:
You should really consider using:

```
pm2 start npm --  start
```

as it will run production build, not development (I know OP asked question with *develop*, but it is important feature considering app being in production.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the setup that I use for using pm2 with next.js:

in the root directory of your app, create an ecosystem.config.js file with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'YourAppNameHere',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: 'max', // Or a number of instances
      script: './node_modules/next/dist/bin/next',
      args: 'start',
      exp_backoff_restart_delay: 100, // optional, adjust as needed
      watch: true, // optional, adjust as needed
      max_memory_restart: '400M' // optional, adjust as needed
    }
  ]
}
```

and then on your server, in the root directory of your app (where the ecosystem.config.js file is) run:

```
pm2 start
```

and following the directions for startup here: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

I use this method vs the other answers above, because I use bitbucket pipelines to deploy and I run the build script in a docker container, which makes it error out if I use `npm run start` to start the script.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple fast approach would be

```
pm2 start "npm run dev" --name AppName
```

where in your case it would be,

```
pm2 start "npm run develop" --name AppName
```

> Note AppName is the name to call your app for easy identification in pm2

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can

```
 pm2 start npm --name name_of_the_app -- start --port your_port
```

e.g

```
pm2 start npm --name abhimanyu -- start --port 3000
```

Here my app name is (abhimanyu) which is running on port 3000

Note: If you do not provide the port number then it will use the default port which is specified on your project

To get the list of the project which is running in pm2 type

```
pm2 list
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the case of using `yarn` alongside `nextjs` and sort out a specific port:

```
pm2 start yarn -- start --port 5500
```