# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'pipefail'

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, pm2

I am having this issue when I try to deploy NodeJS app (built with NextJS) using pm2. I follow the instruction described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70361967/10152123).

My attempt to execute `pm2 start` command seemed working, as shown by the snippet below.

`┌────┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐ │ id │ name               │ mode     │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ memory   │ ├────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┤ │ 0  │ experti            │ fork     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 25.7mb   │ └────┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘`

But when I run `pm2 list`, the previous execution turned out to be error.
`┌────┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐ │ id │ name               │ mode     │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ memory   │ ├────┼────────────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┤ │ 0  │ process            │ fork     │ 15   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ └────┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘`

I checked the pm2 logs as described by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55828215/10152123) and it led me to this log:
`

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'pipefail'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/equitica/.npm/_npx/5f7878ce38f1eb13/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
/home/<username>/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/shims/npm:4
set -o pipefail
       ^^^^^^^^
```

`

So, I checked the file that specified by the log, and found this line (shown below):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
set -o pipefail <-- this line is probably the problem
```

I have no idea what the line means, and have no clue to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing the `/home/<username>/.asdf/plugins/nodejs/shims/npm` file and then execute `pm2 start npm --name <process> -- run start`.