# how to start nextJS project using pm2

Tags: next.js, pm2

Looks like I keep getting errors when trying to run my Next.js project with PM2, even after I've built it. Any ideas on how to fix this?
However, when I try it with npm start, everything runs smoothly without any issues.

[error when try start pm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJDvC.png)
[npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06umZ.png)

Here is the content of my package.json file.
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRQyX.png)

Comment: Please do not post text in images, edit the question to remove all of the images and post the text instead

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352826/can-i-use-pm2-to-keep-a-next-js-app-running

Comment: @AndyRay sorry, i'm newbie, idk how to do that

Comment: @Sarkar yes i was try all of this answer, but i still can't run my nextJS project using pm2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image error and package.json the pm2 command line is like this

`pm2 start "npm run start" --name frontend`

Comment: [PM2][ERROR] Script not found: E:\magang-batch5\projek1\frontend\display\npm run start

Comment: Run in the root of your project,.. in the E:\magang-batch5\projek1\frontend\

Comment: still error
[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: E:\magang-batch5\projek1\frontend\npm run start

Comment: where your package.json,.. run it there ?

Comment: My package.json is in the display folder, and i'm running it in the same folder